# strace output question

Tags: c, linux, binary, centos, strace

I run a program on both CentOS and Debian. The output is exactly the same but in Centos I get the 3 lines in bold while in Debian I do not. What are those 3 lines about and how can I get them in Debian too ?

```
execve("./z1", ["./z1"], [/* 31 vars */]) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x8458000
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
mmap2(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb7f41000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/home/myuser/public_html/libs/libmudflap.so.0", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\3\0\1\0\0\0PJ\0\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=105432, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 943136, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0xd89000
mmap2(0xda2000, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x19) = 0xda2000
mmap2(0xda3000, 836640, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xda3000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/home/myuser/public_html/libs/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\3\0\1\0\0\0\320m\1\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1327556, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb7f40000
mmap2(NULL, 1337704, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x891000
mprotect(0x9d1000, 4096, PROT_NONE)     = 0
mmap2(0x9d2000, 12288, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x140) = 0x9d2000
mmap2(0x9d5000, 10600, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x9d5000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/home/myuser/public_html/libs/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\3\0\1\0\0\0@\n\0\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=9736, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 12408, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x74e000
mmap2(0x750000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1) = 0x750000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb7f3f000
set_thread_area({entry_number:-1 -> 6, base_addr:0xb7f3f6c0, limit:1048575, seg_32bit:1, contents:0, read_exec_only:0, limit_in_pages:1, seg_not_present:0, useable:1}) = 0
open("/dev/urandom", O_RDONLY)          = 3
read(3, "\f\233\37", 3)                 = 3
close(3)                                = 0
mprotect(0x750000, 4096, PROT_READ)     = 0
```

Comment: Why do you want to get them in Debian if you don't know what they do? What is the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: You can always hook up gdb, set a break point on `open`, add the condition for filenam `/dev/urandom` and run... You'll see exactly what calls it

Answer (score 4):

I don't think it has anything to do with strace.  I am not for sure, but it probably has something to do with how things are arranged in memory.  I know some systems place parts of the binary at random places in memory to protect against malicous activities.  This is called [Address Space Layout Randomization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) (ASLR).  I'm guessing then that CentOS is using this and that Debian is not.  See [this post](http://lists.centos.org/pipermail/centos/2008-December/069307.html) about disabling ASLR in CentOS.  Try that and see if strace still shows /dev/urandom being opened.

So the point is that it may be your system, not strace or the program that is causing the discrepancy.

-- Edit --

So I may be wrong above.  I have done a ton of research into this question, and have managed to narrow it down.  What I found is that it is most likely a library making these calls.  The method I used was a bit involved, but doable.  [See this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5863115/gdb-break-when-program-opens-specific-file) on how it's done if you are still curious.

I did this debugging using eye of gnome (eog), because the simple test program I wrote did not trigger the reads of urandom.  It turns out that Gkt+ was the culprit in my case, it uses random numbers to create unique id's for some objects.  I am curious to know what you program is using that makes these calls.  At this point I doubt it is ASLR.