# How do I set a breakpoint/watchpoint on a fortran IO unit in gdb?

Tags: fortran, gdb, gfortran

Consider the statement:

```
      open(unit=24,file='energy_check.out',status='unknown')
```

and elsewhere, in another file in the code:

```
       write(24,*) x
```

and elsewhere, in another file in the code:

```
       write(24,*) y
```

I want to watch/break every time IO is performed on unit 24. How to do this. Web search was not helpful.

Comment: Place a breakpoint on all such statements. I don't know of any other way. I don't thank gdb knows *that* much about Fortran to watch I/O units. You could set a conditional breakpoint in libgfortran, but I don't think it would be too useful.

Comment: This may help (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049424/how-to-stop-program-in-gdb-at-writing-to-a-particular-file-known-by-its-name)

Comment: Are all the writes to 24 of single values of the same type or does it vary?  If they are single values of the same type, change to write statements to 24 to a subroutine and just set the breakpoint in the subroutine.

Comment: @M.Chinoune, that will break every write including other units, many of them will be annoying because they might be in do loops.

Comment: 0
down vote
grep -n "write(24" FortFile.f where I assume the source code is FortFile.f Now you can get a better view of the lines where you have to place breakpoints. There is also an option to place that in a script and run it from gdb. Thanks!

Comment: Does anyone know if there would be a pointer address associated with unit 24? I could "watch" that memory location.