# How can you track a file edit in gdb?

Tags: c, file, gdb, breakpoints

So I am trying to gdb a huge running process. I want to know the exact place where a certain file xyz gets edited by it. Is there a way I can add a breakpoint at the exact line where file write (just for that particular file) happens ?

Comment: Do you mean that a file is being opened and edited by `open(2)`, `write(2)` in the program that you are inspecting?

Comment: This may be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5863115/gdb-break-when-program-opens-specific-file

Comment: @Shurane I don't know for sure.

Comment: Wow, that is an awesome Q&A combination there, @Simon.

Comment: @Simon I guess that's what I need eventually, but it won't serve my purpose, thanks anyways

Comment: if you are on linux you could find the FD via /proc/<pid>/fd/ and then set a conditional breakpoint in on the write() function to let it break on the exact file. not sure if this matches your purpose?